# Masonry or Alternative: Equal Height per Column

Tags: javascript, gallery, masonry

Can I use masonry and force it to keep equal height per column, like flickr or pixieset - rather than staggering images?

EDIT: Also, I want the images to be resized to the height of the column.

http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

Or, is there an alternative that will do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should check out flexbox it should allow you to do what you want: http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback